# Animation and flex space-between layout

Tags: react-native, expo

I have 3 blocks disposed using `justifyContent: 'space-between'`.

The bottom block should be animated (bounce in loop) in height for 100 units in the grey area. The problem is I can't edit margins of the bottom block because `justifyContent` prop causes the middle block moves (first and middle block should be fixed).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Easing, Animated, // Button,
ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
    this.animate(Easing.bounce)
  }

  animate (easing) {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
      Animated.timing(
        this.animatedValue,
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          easing
        }
    ).start( ()=> this.animate(Easing.bounce))
  }

  render () {
    const marginBottom = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 100]
        })
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column',alignItems:"center",justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <View style={styles.block}><Text>top</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.block}>><Text>second</Text></View>

                        <View style={{textAlign: "center",height:150,backgroundColor:"#555"}}>
                            <Animated.View style={[styles.block2, {marginBottom} ]}>
                            <Text style={{position:"absolute"}} >bottom</Text>
                            </Animated.View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  block: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red',

  },
   block2: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/@alfredopacino/animations-easing

To be more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish. It is just this plain and simple animation https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_nunJMjdsAkjvbE4_URc4GIsoDw8M7KN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your marginBottom to marginTop

```
        <View style={{ textAlign: "center", height: 150, backgroundColor: "#555" }}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.block2, { marginTop:marginBottom }]}>//<-changes--
            <Text style={{ position: "absolute" }}>bottom</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
```